# Dropping observations in panel data

Tags: stata

I have a panel data set over three years 87 90 93 for 50 different states. For my variable of interest, `exec`, I want to drop all entries for the `state` where `exec == 0` in each of the years and only if it equals zero in each of the years.

I've been trying to write some sort of for loop but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2):

No loop is needed. No extra variable is needed.

```
bysort state (exec) : drop if exec[1] == 0 & exec[_N] == 0
```

will `drop` observations for a `state` if and only if all values of `exec` are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work assuming exec can't be negative:

```
webuse airacc
bysort airline (time): egen tot = total(inprog)
drop if tot==0
```

This will drop airlines where the sum of inprog across time for each state is zero, treating missings as zeros.

`egen` and `egenmore` will save you from getting loopy.